# Non-Attacking Queens

Tags: chess, algorithm

Consider the problem of N queen on an (NxN) chessboard. Two queens are said to attack each other if they are on the same row, column,
or diagonal. Implements backtracking algorithm to solve the problem i.e. place N non-attacking queens on the board.